# Parsing json jquery

Tags: json, jquery

My request ajax with json_encode:

```
[{"idHome":"1","Photo":"home-1.jpg","Publier":"1"},
{"idHome":"2","Photo":"home2.jpg","Publier":"1"}, 
{"idHome":"3","Photo":"home3.jpg","Publier":"1"}]

var string = JSON.stringify(data);

var obj = $.parseJSON(string);

console.log(string);

var idHome = obj.idHome;

var photo = obj.Photo;


console.log(obj.idHome);

console.log(obj.Photo);
```

Problem with parsing json

console log :

```
[{"idHome":"1","Photo":"home-1.jpg","Publier":"1"},{"idHome":"2","Photo":"home-2.jpg","Publier":"1"},{"idHome":"3","Photo":"home-3.jpg","Publier":"1"}]

undefined

undefined
```

Comment: Why not use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.ajax`?

Comment: I use $.ajax !  $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        data: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',

Comment: You've encoded an array... `console.log(obj[0]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an array so you need to loop through, there are so many ways to do it.

```
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    console.log(obj[i].idHome);
    console.log(obj[i].Photo);
}
```

or:

```
obj.forEach(function(val) {
    console.log(val.idHome);
    console.log(val.Photo);
});
```

or:

```
for (var i in obj) {
    console.log(obj[i].idHome);
    console.log(obj[i].Photo);
}
```

Jquery use :

```
 $.each(obj, function(_, val){
    console.log(val.idHome);
    console.log(val.Photo);
 });
```

and so on....

Comment: Jquery use parse just {"idHome":"1","Photo":"home1.jpg","Publier":"1"}

Comment: @boube You want only the first one?

Answer (score 2):

Your json is an array of three objects.

Try

```
console.log(obj[0].idHome);
console.log(obj[0].Photo);
```

More info:
http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp